# Is there a way to show an entire div with content, only when two (both) checkboxes are clicked, using jquery/js or just html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core, razor

Basically I need parts of a form to show only when both checkboxes are selected,for example in this particular case I need one checkbox for "Individual" checked, then when "managed by team admins" is checked, a div shows with a further few options.

The issue I'm facing is that the "Managed by teams, and the other checkbox for the same category (direct entry) need to be visible when both of the first criteria is met. For example when either "individual", and the alternate option "teams" are checked, both "manged by team admins" & "direct entry" needs to show, though if "Teams" is selected and "Managed by team admins", the div that would show if "individual" was checked should not show.

I apologise for my probably terrible explanation, but any help would be appreciated

```
<div class="form-page-content">
  <div class="style-full-checkbox link-selection" data-link=".type-radio" data-type="radio">
    <div id="individualButton" data-checked="#INDTC" class="active">Individual team type</div>
    <div data-checked="#TEAMTC">Teams representing a team category</div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <label class="type-radio">
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Competition.CompetitionEntryType, true, new { @id = "INDTC", @group =
      "IndividualTeam", @checked = "checked", style = "display:none", @class = "enable-view", data_link = ".INDTC",
      data_linkHide = ".TEAMTC" })
    </label>
    <label for="enablepaygate" class="type-radio">
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Competition.CompetitionEntryType, false, new { @id = "TEAMTC", @group = "Teamtype",
      style = "display:none", @class = "enable-view", data_link = ".TEAMTC", data_linkHide = ".INDTC" })
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="INDTC">
    <div class="style-input-group style-input-group-mobile" data-required="true" data-limit="30">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Competition.MaxEntrants, new { })
      <span class="input-bar"></span>
      <label class="label">Max Entrants (0 = Unlimited)</label>
      <label class="error" style=""></label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-page-content">
      <div class="style-full-checkbox link-selection" data-link=".type-radio" data-type="radio">
        <div id="DirectButtonIN" data-checked="#nonDirectIN" class="active">Managed</div>
        <div data-checked="#DirectIN">Direct</div>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden">
        <label class="type-radio">
          @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Competition.DirectEntry, true, new { @id = "DirectIN", @group = "DirectEntry",
          style = "display:none", @class = "enable-view", data_link = "#DirectContainerIN", data_linkHide = "#ManagedIN"
          })
        </label>
        <label for="enablepaygate" class="type-radio">
          @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Competition.DirectEntry, false, new { @id = "nonDirectIN", @group = "DirectEnry",
          @checked = "checked", style = "display:none", @class = "enable-view", data_link = "#ManagedIN", data_linkHide
          = "#DirectContainerIN" })
        </label>
      </div>
      <div id="DirectContainerIN" style="display: none;">
        <div class="form-group direct-true" style="margin:0px; padding-bottom:5px;">
          <label>Allow payment deferral</label>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign tt" rel="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-container="body"
            data-placement="auto top"
            data-content="Ticking this will allow members to defer any costs to their Team Administrator. The entry fee can then be paid at a later date."></i>
          @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Competition.AllowDeferral)
        </div>

      </div>
      <div id="ManagedIN" style="display: none;">
        <div class="style-input-group style-input-group-mobile" data-required="true" data-limit="30">
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Competition.MinPlayersPerTeam, new { })
          <span class="input-bar"></span>
          <label class="label">Min players</label>
          <label class="error" style=""></label>
        </div>

        <div class="style-input-group style-input-group-mobile" data-required="true" data-limit="30">
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Competition.MaxPlayersPerTeam, new { })
          <span class="input-bar"></span>
          <label class="label">Max players</label>
          <label class="error" style=""></label>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="TEAMTC" style="display:none;">
    <div class="form-page-content">
      <div class="style-full-checkbox link-selection" data-link=".type-radio" data-type="radio">
        <div id="DirectButtonTeam" data-checked="#nonDirectTeam" class="active">Managed</div>
        <div data-checked="#DirectTeam">Direct</div>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden">
        <label class="type-radio">
          @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Competition.DirectEntry, true, new { @id = "DirectTeam", @group = "DirectEntry",
          style = "display:none", @class = "enable-view", data_link = "#DirectContainerTeam", data_linkHide =
          "#ManagedTeam" })
        </label>
        <label for="enablepaygate" class="type-radio">
          @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Competition.DirectEntry, false, new { @id = "nonDirectTeam", @group =
          "DirectEnry", @checked = "checked", style = "display:none", @class = "enable-view", data_link =
          "#ManagedTeam", data_linkHide = "#DirectContainerTeam" })
        </label>
      </div>
      <div id="DirectContainerTeam" style="display: none;">
        <div class="form-group direct-true" style="margin:0px; padding-bottom:5px;">
          <label>Allow payment deferral</label>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign tt" rel="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-container="body"
            data-placement="auto top"
            data-content="Ticking this will allow members to defer any costs to their Team Administrator. The entry fee can then be paid at a later date."></i>
          @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Competition.AllowDeferral)
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My idea would be to add an if statement into the "managed teams" div, that checks if the teamtype is INDTC before rendering the content, but I don't know how to do this with Razor, as it only runs on load. I'm assuming this would be a job for some custom JS but I'm not sure how.

Comment: From your title I believe that it's possible, but it's not possible to give you a good answer without seeing your code, Please include all relevant code like html, jQuery.

Comment: Updated with more info

Comment: Where is your "Individual" and "manged by team admins" checbox?And what does `though if "Teams" is selected and "Managed by team admins", the div that would show if "individual" was checked should not show.` mean?If you wan to show or hidden div when checkbox change,you can use `$("checkbox").change(function(){xxxxxxx})`.